# Integrating KafkaProducer into Jersey REST

Tags: java, rest, jersey, apache-kafka

I have a sample Hello World REST API and I've written some simple Kafka producer code.

Now I want my Kafka Producer to send message to a topic every time REST API is invoked, i.e. when someone enters *www.mywebpage.com/entry-api/test* I want my producer to send message to a topic.

Easiest way would be to create new producer instance every time and send a single message, but that seems just plain stupid. So I figured out there must be a way to inject this Kafka producer instance into Jersey resource so that producer would be created with server and closed one server is closed.

I've read that I could do it with Dependency Injection, but I got lost what actually I should do and how it works.

I would very much appreciate some guidelines how should I change my code so that injection of Kafka producer would work.

Code below.

Here is my main class:

```
package org.apache.kafka;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");

        Server jettyServer = new Server(9090);
        jettyServer.setHandler(context);

        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
             org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

        // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
           "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
           EntryApi.class.getCanonicalName());

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.join();
        } finally {
            jettyServer.destroy();
        }

    }

}
```

Here is resource:

```
package org.apache.kafka;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/entry-api")
public class EntryApi {

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void test() {
        //HERE I WANT TO SEND MESSAGE WITH KAFKA PRODUCER
    }
}
```

I also have Kafka Producer written:

```
package org.apache.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class SampleProducer {

    private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;

    public SampleProducer() {
        Properties prodProp = new Properties();

        prodProp.put("bootstrap.servers", "sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667");
        prodProp.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        prodProp.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        prodProp.put("request.required.acks", "1");

        this.producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(prodProp);
    }

    public void sendMsgToTopic(String inMessage) {

        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(inMessage);

        ProducerRecord<String, String> msgData = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("testTopic", msg.toString());
        Future<RecordMetadata> rs = producer.send(msgData, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata rM, Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Received ack for partition=" + rM.partition() + " offset=" + rM.offset());
            }
        });

        try {
            RecordMetadata rM = (RecordMetadata) rs.get();
            msg.append(" partition=" + rM.partition() + " offset=" + rM.offset());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void closeProducer() {
        this.producer.close();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Ok, so I got it working on my sandbox with Jersey 2.x (thanks to **peeskillet**).

Thing is, I have to make it work with Jersey 1.18 (that's the requirement :()

Again, thanks to **peeskillet** I've got it working with something like this:

```
    @Provider
public class KafkaProducerProvider implements InjectableProvider<Inject, Type>{

    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope() {
        return ComponentScope.Singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable<SampleProducer> getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Inject a, Type c) {
        if (c.equals(SampleProducer.class)) {
            return new Injectable<SampleProducer>() {

                @Override
                public SampleProducer getValue() {

                    Properties prodProp = new Properties();
                    prodProp.put("bootstrap.servers", "sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667");
                    prodProp.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
                    prodProp.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
                    prodProp.put("request.required.acks", "1");

                    return new SampleProducer(prodProp);
                }

            };
        }
```

Comment: What Jersey version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Jersey 1.18.1.

Comment: I just noticed something. You are using `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` and `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames`. which is Jersey 2.x. I'm taking it you are mistaken when you say you are using Jersey 1.18.1. The solution to your problem is alot easier with Jersey 2.x then is it with 1.x, that's why I ask. Can you please clarify

Comment: You're right, sorry for the mess. It's 2.7.
But I think I'll just implement it as signleton like you suggested as it seems the most simple solution.

Comment: Problem with the singleton is that it's impossible to unit test your resource class, since it's tightly coupled with the kafka access code. I would instead program to an interface, inject the interface. That way in a unit test you can mock out the interface. The answer below shows how injection would work wit the concrete class, but you can easily change it to using an interface with `bind(Impl.class).to(Interface.class)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some playing around, it looks like shutting down single services is not as easy as I thought it would be. I thought we could just annotate a method with `@PreDestroy`, but I guess it's not that easy

Injection is no problem. This is really all you need

```
public class InjectionFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {

        context.register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(SampleProducer.class)
                        .to(SampleProducer.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also bind any other service you want to, in the same `configure` method. Then you just need to add the feature to the classes

```
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
       "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
       EntryApi.class.getCanonicalName() + ","
       + InjectionFeature.class.getCanonicalName());
```

You should now be able to just inject it into your resource class

```
@Path("/entry-api")
public class EntryApi {

    @Inject
    private SampleProducer producer;
```

The problem is with closing, if you want clean anything up before shutdown. The only way I was able to find, is to implement an `ApplicationEventListener`

```
public class ApplicationListener implements ApplicationEventListener {

    @Inject
    private ServiceLocator locator;

    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent ae) {
        switch (ae.getType()) {
            case DESTROY_FINISHED: {
                SampleProducer producer = locator.getService(SampleProducer.class);
                producer.destroy();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent re) {
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Here you are looking up the `SampleProducer` and closing it yourself.
Just register the listener the same way as the feature above.

**See Also:**

- [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html)
- [Event Listeners](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e15562)

Comment: Could I also add feature using this param?
setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
                                     "org.apache.kafka")

Comment: Yes you can, but with Jersey 2.x it's actually `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`. What you have there is for 1.x. If you are going to package scan, make sure the two classes above are annotated with `@Provider`. That's how they will be discovered. Resource classes only need `@Path` .That's how _they_ will be discovered

Comment: Ok, so I got it working on my sandbox with Jersey 2.x.

Thing is, I have to make it work with Jersey 1.18 (that's the requirement :()

I've edited main post. How do I go about it?

Comment: return `ComponentScope.Singleton` for the `ComponentScope` and return an anonymous class (or instance of implementation) of `Injectable<SampleProducer>` in the `getInjectable`. Return the actual instance in the `getValue()`

Comment: Like this?

@Override
    public SampleProducer getValue() {
     return new SampleProducer();
    }

Wouldn't this return new instance of SampleProducer every time?

Comment: Not if you return `ComponentScope.Singleton` in `getScope()`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot, very helpful! :)